# Filter a message from custom pipeline

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

I ran into another issue with BizTalk 2010. I am supposed to receive a collection of records in form of XML. The XML I receive is an envelop with multiple record inside. My simple task was to debatch the records inside the XML and put them into a different folder without using orchestration. I had created an xsd that held the structure of the record, then another xsd which was the envelope containing the previous xsd which I imported it. I did have an xpath-body that pointed to the xsd envelope. Everything until now appeared to work fine as I had generated an XML from the xsd with envelope and did use xmldasm.exe to test it. The results were satisfactory as the XML was debatched into multiple records in XML format as expected.

I, then, created a custom receive pipeline with XML disassembler only and set up the proper document, then deployed the project successfully. From the admin console, I configured my application, created a receive port and send port which were of type FILE. From the send port, I set the filter to `BTS.MessageType == MyTestProject.MyXsdRoot`.

Finally, I have successfully started my application.

However, when I dropped a testing envelope XML with multiple record (the one I have tested using xmlDasm.exe above) in the InputFolder, the XML in the folder was consumed but nothing were generated in the OutputFolder. From the console, I saw a routing error (resumable). Obviously, I have overlooked something due to my lack of BizTalk experience.

Could someone with more knowledge point out what was wrong or what I should do to find out what was wrong?

Update:

-------- Envelope ----------------------------------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" ?> 
- <xs:schema xmlns="http://UsingOrchestration.SetOfProcedures" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" xmlns:ns0="http://UsingOrchestration.Procedures" targetNamespace="http://UsingOrchestration.SetOfProcedures" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:import schemaLocation="UsingOrchestration.Procedure" namespace="http://UsingOrchestration.Procedures" /> 
- <xs:annotation>
- <xs:appinfo>
  <b:schemaInfo is_envelope="yes" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" /> 
- <b:references>
  <b:reference targetNamespace="http://UsingOrchestration.Procedures" /> 
  </b:references>
  </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
- <xs:element name="SetOfProcedures">
- <xs:annotation>
- <xs:appinfo>
  <b:recordInfo body_xpath="/*[local-name()='SetOfProcedures' and namespace-uri()='http://UsingOrchestration.SetOfProcedures']" /> 
  </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
- <xs:complexType>
- <xs:sequence>
  <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="ns0:ProcedureCompleted" /> 
  </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
```

---------------------Actual Message-------------------

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" ?> 
- <xs:schema xmlns="http://UsingOrchestration.Procedures" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" targetNamespace="http://UsingOrchestration.Procedures" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
- <xs:element name="ProcedureCompleted">
- <xs:complexType>
- <xs:sequence>
  <xs:element name="AltID" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="RotationName" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="ProcedureID" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="ProcedureFee" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="Comment" type="xs:string" /> 
  </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
--------- Test xml------------------------------------------
<ns0:SetOfProcedures xmlns:ns0="http://UsingOrchestration.SetOfProcedures">
  <ns1:ProcedureCompleted xmlns:ns1="http://UsingOrchestration.Procedures">
    <AltID>AltID_0</AltID>
    <RotationName>RotationName_0</RotationName>
    <ProcedureID>ProcedureID_0</ProcedureID>
    <ProcedureFee>ProcedureFee_0</ProcedureFee>
    <Comment>Comment_0</Comment>
  </ns1:ProcedureCompleted>
  <ns1:ProcedureCompleted xmlns:ns1="http://UsingOrchestration.Procedures">
    <AltID>AltID_1</AltID>
    <RotationName>RotationName_1</RotationName>
    <ProcedureID>ProcedureID_1</ProcedureID>
    <ProcedureFee>ProcedureFee_1</ProcedureFee>
    <Comment>Comment_1</Comment>
  </ns1:ProcedureCompleted>
  <ns1:ProcedureCompleted xmlns:ns1="http://UsingOrchestration.Procedures">
    <AltID>AltID_2</AltID>
    <RotationName>RotationName_2</RotationName>
    <ProcedureID>ProcedureID_2</ProcedureID>
    <ProcedureFee>ProcedureFee_2</ProcedureFee>
    <Comment>Comment_2</Comment>
  </ns1:ProcedureCompleted>
</ns0:SetOfProcedures>
```

With the exact same XML, I can filter it by `BTS.ReceivePortName`, the set was debatched correctly but that does not process at all when I filter it by `BTS.MessageType`. I must have missed something, just do not know what.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you followed all the steps in the following [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee277658%28v=bts.10%29.aspx). Perhaps you might have forgot to set the **Envelope** property on the schema. Moreover, you do not need a custom pipeline for XML debatching as the default XMLReceive pipeline is capable of doing that.

Comment: I did have envelope property set and did have xpath-body set. I just can not filter it out by BTS.MessageType for some reason. I worked around and filter it out by port name and my message got processed.

Comment: Thanks! Please see my update in the post as comment does not have enough space for my schema

Comment: That could very well be the case! Let me correct this when I come back to work tomorrow and let you know. Thanks!!

Comment: I corrected the xml to using "UsingOrchestration.SetOfProcedures" and changed the filter to BTS.MessageType==UsingOrchestration.SetOfProcedures. The message got taken out but still not processed. EventViewer shows the following error: "The published message could not be routed because no subscribers were found. This error occurs if the subscribing orchestration or send port has not been enlisted, or if some of the message properties necessary for subscription evaluation have not been promoted. Please use the Biztalk Administration console to troubleshoot this failure. "

Comment: The same as the no of messages in the envelope. There are 3 suppended(not resumable) of MessageTypes "http://UsingOrchestration.Procedures" with Routing Failure Report for 'RP2' (RP2 is the receive port name) and one Suspended(resumable) message with MessageType being blank. I wish I could upload the screen capture of what I see from the console.

Comment: By subscription criteria, do you mean setting up the filters? If so, yes I did have a filter on the send port with property using BTS.MessageType and value being UsingOrchestration.Procedures (no quote). It was not working for me... :(